# batch - Why does successful dir statement print File Not Found?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Recently, I made a small batch file to list all of the files in a given directory.  When I run the file, it successfully makes a txt of all of the files.  However, if I run it from the command prompt, it also prints `File Not Found`.

```
dir ".\builds\dev-versions" /b /o:d *.jar > devFiles.txt
```

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: The starting directory is different. ALWAYS use FULL PATHS

Comment: Would have never occurred to me to split apart the file path and the file name like that.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to run `dir ".\builds\dev-versions\*.jar" /b /o:d >devFiles.txt` or a bit shorter `dir "builds\dev-versions\*.jar" /b /o:d >devFiles.txt` to get a list of all *.jar files in subdirectory `builds\dev-versions` of current directory ordered by last modification date. But you ran __DIR__ to get a list of all files in subdirectory `builds\dev-versions` and additionally a list of all `*.jar` files in current directory. The search for *.jar files in current directory fails. Run in a command prompt window `dir /?` for help on this command.

Comment: I didn't know the wildcard `*jar` needed to be put in the file path, although I suppose it makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dir` command should be running twice - once for each of the arguments `".\builds\dev-versions"` and `*.jar`

`.` means "the current directory" so it should list both the nominated directory, and all of the `.jar` files in the current directory. If either list is empty, you'll get the `file nor found` error.

Since you don't tell us what the code is attempting to do, we are limited in suggesting a remedy. Appending `2>nul` may assist by discarding the error report.